# how to insert Datagridview data to my database

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, modal-dialog, ado.net

I am building a fastcell application for companies or other markets.

I want to show all my staff in Datagridview and when the click save button ı insert Datagridview elements to database with using EntityFramework.

Also ı want to add only Datagridview items which has ıd number in Datagridview.

Ho can ı do that ? How can ı insert to table Datagridview items for each row(uniqe primary key only)?

I am using ADO.NET Entity Database Model framework.

```
public void SepetiNetsisAktar()
        {
            using (fastCellDb db = new fastCellDb())
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvSepet.Rows)
                {
                    stokModel.stokAdi = row.Cells["stokAdi"]
                    db.xstHars.Add(stokHarModel);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my way but it is not working  well.

And how am ı show Datagridview elements;

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Id");
            dt.Columns.Add("Ürün");
            dt.Columns.Add("Fiyat");
            dt.Columns.Add("Miktar");
            dt.Columns.Add("Toplam");
            dgvSepet.DataSource = dt;

            dgvSepet.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
```

and call it like that ;

```
public void SepeteUrunEkle()
        {
            stokModel.Id = Convert.ToInt32(lblStokID.Text);

            using (fastCellDb db = new fastCellDb())
            {
                stokModel = db.xstSabits.Where(x => x.Id == stokModel.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                //dgv cells
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = stokModel.Id;
                dr[1] = stokModel.stokAdi;
                dr[2] = stokModel.satisFiyati1;
                dr[3] = txtMiktar.Text;
                dr[4] = Convert.ToDecimal(stokModel.satisFiyati1) * Convert.ToDecimal(txtMiktar.Text);

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                GetToplamFaturaFiyati();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are all these rows new? or are you updating existing records? How do you initially fill the DataGridView?

Comment: ı edited the question with how am ı connect Datagridview

Comment: ı am adding with SepeteUrunEkle() function to Datagridview after that ı want to insert this Datagridview elements to table with SepetiNetsiseAktar()